# strange execution order requirement on two monadic actions in Hint (Language.Haskell.Interpreter)

Tags: haskell, ghc, hint, side-effects

In the code at the bottom, two monadic actions (`loadModules` and `setImportsQ`) in Hint (Language.Haskell.Interpreter) can only be executed in one order but not the other, as shown in a minimal example below. In particular, `loadModules` must go first, or else the following exception will be generated when executing the interpreter.

```
*** Exception: compile error: WontCompile [GhcError {errMsg = "Not in scope: type
 constructor or class `Int'"}]
```

This behavior seems to have been introduced in `Hint 0.4.1.0`. I must have missed something obvious..

My first questions is Hint specific: why must `loadModules` be called before `setImportsQ`?

My second question is more general: it seems that these two monadic actions do NOT feed input into each other, also the to-be-loaded module is empty, why is the order or execution important at all? This almost reminds me of the imperative world, where you not only have to worry about the input/output, but also the order of certain side effects.

The code is below. Note that `MyModule.hs` is an empty .hs file.

```
module Main where

import Language.Haskell.Interpreter
import Control.Monad

custom=["MyModule"] --mymodule.hs is just an empty .hs source file in the same folder
context=[("Data.Int",Nothing)]

main = do
  x <- interp ("1") (as ::Int)
  return ()

interp e as_type = do
  interpreterResult <- runInterpreter $ do
     loadModules custom     --this line must go first
     setImportsQ context    --this line must go second
     interpret e as_type
  f <- case interpreterResult of
        Left e -> error $ "compile error: " ++ show e
        Right result -> return result
  return f
```